# passing unsigned char array to string functions

Tags: c, utf-8

Say I have some utf8 encoded string. Inside it words are delimited using `";"`.
But each character (except `";"`) inside this string has *utf8 value >128*.
Say I store this string inside `unsigned char` array:

```
unsigned char buff[]="someutf8string;separated;with;";
```

Is it safe to pass this `buff` to `strtok` function? (If I just want to extracts words using `";"` symbol).

My concern is that `strtok` (or also `strcpy`) expect `char` pointers, but inside my
string some values will have value > 128.
So is this behaviour defined?

Comment: `strtok` is locale independant, so it shouldn't have any trouble with what you want it for.

Comment: @AntonH: yes but what about strcpy for example?

Comment: `strcpy` looks for the null-terminator, and UTF-8 encoding doesn't have a 0 character, AFAIK. So it shouldn't be an issue either. BUt if you want, wait a bit and someone else will come along and either confirm or disprove what I said. Some info here: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=806

Comment: UTF-8 **does** have a 0 character - the same 0 character that ASCII has, since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 - Unicode `U+0000`, encoded as byte octet `0x00` just like in ASCII.

Comment: @AntonH: The null byte is the UTF-8 encoding of U+0000.  It does have that, but its purpose is unchanged, so most string functions that look for a zero byte will be OK with UTF-8 (and the null byte never appears in UTF-8 as part of another character).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I wasn't clear in what I wanted to say. I meant that the `\x00` has no particular **meaning** in UTF-8, rather than it **doesn't exist**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C11 Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.24.1 String Handling Conventions, ¶3, emphasis added):

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be
>   interpreted as if it had the type **`unsigned char`** (and therefore every
>   possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

<sup>*Note: this paragraph was not present in the C99 standard.*</sup>

So I do not see a problem.

Comment: When the UTF8 encoding scheme was invented, one of the goals was to allow C string library routines handle them safely, even though the routines do not know about Unicode. In particular, you can safely copy them, compare them, sort them, and work with ascii-7-subset characters as is. (From a paper by Dennis Ritchie?)

Comment: It was Ken Thompson, not Dennis Ritchie, who devised UTF8. Here's a memo about the design objectives: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/utf-8-history.txt

Comment: Is that clause saying that the characters are read as `(unsigned char)*p`, or as `*(unsigned char *)p` ?  (for non-2's complement negative values, these are different)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think the cast after the dereference makes the most sense. Is there anything of particular concern to you in the subtlety of the difference between the two?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I agree that makes more sense, however if it is true then `unsigned char buf[] = "e"; strchr( (char *)buf, 'e' )` could fail   if `'e'` is negative. The value of `'e'` is converted to unsigned char when stored in `buf` , but aliasing it back to signed char could result in a different character than `'e'`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I see what you mean: `(unsigned char)'e' != 'e'U` necessarily, particularly with implementations that may pad signed integral values with bits. I think you may have found a bug introduced by one tiny clause in C11. I imagine that any implementation using padding bits would already make `char` unsigned by default because of things like this, but I suppose it is possible that there are some implementations treating it as a signed value, though I'd like to think such a platform would be a bit on the esoteric side. As for negative values, I think I'm blind as to what you mean.

Comment: "negative values": any value that compares less than 0 , e.g. `'e'` in EBCDIC with plain char signed.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune this is all a non-issue in 2's complement but it's always bugged me (the same issue comes up in many places in C99, *technically* aliasing plain char as unsigned char or vice versa could break for this reason although IDK if there has ever been a machine where it actually would break).

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've not worked with EBCDIC systems, but I still fail to comprehend your point. The only issue I can see is an improperly written `strchr` function where `char` is already unsigned, or the function considers each character in the string to be unsigned, while the integral value is left as signed, and 0x00ef is definitely not equal to 0xffef in the case of `'\xef'`. How does one's complement or sign-magnitude affect things when two's complement has no problem? Isn't this merely a signedness issue?

Comment: OK, I'll make a new question about it sometimes instead of having a discussion in comments.

Comment: @ georgem At present I am using  N1548 Committee Draft — December 2, 2010 ISO/IEC 9899:201x

Comment: @georgem  Now I nave no idea why it can be unsafe.

Comment: @georgem Sorry I do not understand whta you are speaking about now.

Comment: @georgem  It is not my note. My post was edited. But in any case the same was valid for C99.

Comment: @giorgim char, unsigned char and signed char are three different types. You should cast a pointer to unsigned char to pointer to character when it is passed to functions that declare the corresponding parameter as char *. Nevertheless within standard string functions character arrays are considered as arrays of unsigned characters.

Comment: @giorgim For example GCC will issue an error if you will use the function without casting.

Comment: @giorgim As I wrote there is nothing dangerous. According to the C Standard "3 For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a
different value)."

Comment: That clause is about the *representation* of characters. It doesn't change the fact that calling `strtok` with an `unsigned char*` argument is a constraint violation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe -- but *if it compiles* it will almost certainly work as expected.

```
unsigned char buff[]="someutf8string;separated;with;";
```

This is fine; the standard specifically permits arrays of character type (including `unsigned char`) to be initialized with a string literal. Successive bytes of the string literal initialize the elements of the array.

```
strtok(buff, ";")
```

This is a *constraint violation*, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. (That's about as close as the C standard gets to saying that something is illegal.)

The first parameter of `strok` is of type `char*`, but  you're passing an argument of type `unsigned char*`. These two pointer types are not compatible, and there is no implicit conversion between them. A conforming compiler may reject your program if it contains a call like this (and, for example, `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` does reject it.)

Many C compilers are somewhat lax about strict enforcement of the standard's requirements. In many cases, compilers issue warnings for code that contains constraint violations -- which is perfectly valid. But once a compiler has diagnosed a constraint violation and proceeded to generate an executable, the behavior of that executable is not defined by the C standard.

As far as I know, any actual compiler that doesn't reject this call will generate code that behaves just as you expect it to. The pointer types `char*` and `unsigned char*` almost certainly have the same representation and are passed the same way as arguments, and the types `char` and `unsigned char` are explicitly required to have the same representation for non-negative values. Even for values exceeding `CHAR_MAX`, like the ones you're using, a compiler would have to go out of its way to generate misbehaving code. You could have problems on a system that doesn't use 2's-complement for signed integers, but yo're not likely to encounter such a system.

If you add an explicit cast:

```
strtok((char*)buff, ";")
```

removes the constraint violation and will probably silence any warning -- but the behavior is still strictly undefined.

In practice, though, most compilers try to treat `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` almost interchangeably, partly to cater to code like yours, and partly because they'd have to go out of their way to do anything else.

Comment: @userq: No, there's no contradiction. A *constraint violation* is an error that must be diagnosed by the compiler. *Undefined behavior* is an error that the compiler is not required to detect.

Comment: @userq: If a C program violates a constraint, a compiler must diagnose it, and may reject it. If it doesn't reject it, its behavior is undefined. A cast removes the constraint violation, but not the UB. "*and if user already has stored her string in an unsigned char array what solution do you recommend if she wants to apply string functions to this buffer/string?*" -- That's a good question. C doesn't seem to guarantee that `char` and `unsigned char` objects are interchangeable, but it still seems to *assume* that they are.

Comment: Plain `char` is commonly signed; UTF-8 requires unsigned 8-bit quantities. IMHO C has not done a good and consistent job of reconciling them. Using the cast: `strtok((char*)buff, ";")` is probably the best approach; it will almost certainly work, even though the language standard doesn't guarantee it.