# Pass unsigned char pointer to atoi without cast

Tags: c, pointers

On some embedded device, I have passed an `unsigned char` pointer to `atoi` *without* a cast.

```
unsigned char c[10]="12";
atoi(c);
```

Question: is it well defined?

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767522/passing-unsigned-char-array-to-string-functions) somewhere it is ok for string functions, but was not sure about `atoi`.

Edit: Btw. Some concerns have been expressed on one of the answer below that it might not be OK even for string functions such as strcpy - but if I got right (?) the author meant also it can be that in practice this can be OK.

---

Also that I am here, is it ok to do following *assignment* to `unsigned char` pointer ok too? Because I used some tool which is complaining about "Type mismatch (assignment) (ptrs to signed/unsigned)"

```
unsigned char *ptr = strtok(unscharbuff,"-");
    // is assignment also ok to unsigned char?
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not well defined. It's a constraint violation, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. In practice it's very very likely to work as you expect, but it's not guaranteed to do so, and IMHO it's poor style.

The `atoi` function is declared in `<stdlib.h>` as:

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

You're passing an `unsigned char*` argument to a function that expects a `char*` argument. The two types are not compatible, and there is no implicit conversion from one to the other. A conforming compiler may issue a warning (that counts as a diagnostic) and then proceed to generate an executable, but the behavior of that executable is undefined.

As of C99, a call to a function with no visible declaration is a constraint violation, so you can't get away with it by omitting the `#include <stdlib.h>`.

C does still permit calls to functions with a visible declaration where the declaration is not a prototype (i.e., doesn't define the number of type(s) of the parameters). So, rather than the usual `#include <stdlib.h>`, you could add your own declaration:

```
int atoi();
```

which would permit calling it with an `unsigned char*` argument.

This will almost certainly "work", and it might be possible to construct an argument from the standard that its behavior is well defined. The `char` and `unsigned char` values of `'1'` and `'2'` are guaranteed to have the same representation

But it's far easier to add the cast than to prove that it's not necessary -- or, better yet, to define `c` as an array of `char` rather than as an array of `unsigned char`, since it's intended to hold a string.

```
unsigned char *ptr = strtok(unscharbuff,"-");
```

This is also a constraint violation. There is no implicit conversion from `unsigned char*` to `char*` for the first argument in the `strtok` call, and there is no implicit conversion from `char*` to `unsigned char*` for the initialization of `ptr`.

Comment: @userq: No, it's a constraint violation. After the implicit conversion, `"Test"` yields a value of type `char*`. There is no implicit conversion from `char*` to `unsigned char*`.

Comment: @userq: `unsigned char arr[] = "Test";` is permitted. There's no pointer conversion; the elements of the string literal are used to initialize the `unsigned char` elements of the array ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.9p14). This applies only to array initialization, not pointer initialization. If I've said otherwise, can you link to the relevant answer so I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these will function perfectly fine.  Your compiler settings will determine whether you get a warning regarding type.  I usually compile with -Wall, to turn on all warnings, and then use static casting in the code for each and every case, so that I know I have carefully examined them.  The end result is zero errors and zero warnings, and any change that triggers a warning in the future will really stand out, not get lost in 100 tolerated messages.

Comment: like I said I didn't use casting; ps this is compiler for some embedded device

Comment: You did not use the casts, but you should do so to silence the warnings and DO keep warnings enabled (`-Wall`) to get useful caveats from the compiler.

Comment: @chqrlie: Ok I was not sure how to pass -Wall to that compiler I am using some make file etc. Was not sure if that compiler supports -Wall?

Comment: @chqrlie: maybe you can back up or show me some docs about this and also my other question which say it is ok? I am interested just for learning purpose

Comment: @User30015: OK.  Here is food for thought: I don't know if you are familiar with the C Standard (you can find the latest draft by looking for n1570.pdf ). `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are different types, but they are guaranteed to occupy the same space and have no padding bits.  It would take a purposely built machine to use a different bit representation for values between 0 and 127 stored as `signed char` and `unsigned char`.  Such a hypothetical machine, the DS9K ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:CompuHacker/CHDS9000 ), would break almost any piece of casual C software.

Comment: @chqrlie: Even the DS9K has to use the same representation for non-negative values of corresponding signed and unsigned types. See N1570 6.2.6.2 paragraphs 1-2.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: you are absolutely correct! Thank you for the definitive answer to this question.  *Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type*.

Comment: @chqrlie: So here you and K. Thompson seem to agree but then he still seems to give a negative answer :)

Comment: @User30015; chqrlie seems to be saying that I agree with him. I don't. The quoted passage discusses the representations of corresponding signed and unsigned types. It doesn't change the fact that pointers to such types are incompatible. As I've been saying, *if* your compiler accepts the code in question, it will very likely work as expected, and you probably have better ways to spend your time than fixing it. But the C standard doesn't guarantee it, and a conforming compiler could either reject it or generate incorrect code for it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes like I said I verified and all their sample codes pass char * to methods expecting unsigned char * s (including methods from their SDK), and sometimes vice versa.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Do you think this is a bad sign and I should start panicing and get in touch with them and notify about this?

Comment: @User30015:  There is no need to panic.  There is also no need to get in touch with them about this, because, as Keith pointed out, you (and they) probably have better ways to spend time.  My expectation is, they will agree the types are technically different, and they won't care, or need to care.

Comment: Panic is not warranted. Passing a `char*` to an function (pedantry alert: C doesn't have "methods") expecting an `unsigned char*` is a constraint violation, but if your compiler accepts it it will almost certainly work as expected. Just keep in mind that it *might* cause problems eventually if you use a stricter compiler, or the same compiler in a stricter mode. For now, from what you say, it works.