# Concatenate a string like in printf

Tags: c, concatenation, coercion

`printf` is beautiful function because it helps you formatting your string in a very clean way.

```
printf("Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

Is there a similar way to concatenate and perform coercion in a "normal string" like below:

```
uint8_t myString = ("Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage); //SOMETHING LIKE THIS
```

Comment: `sprintf()` is your answer

Comment: do you want [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)?

Comment: You may find John Carmack's idea for this functionality interesting, as implemented in the Quake 3 engine: https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena/blob/master/code/splines/q_shared.cpp (line 700). Note that you need a sufficiently deep buffer or funny things could happen with nested calls, and of course this is a big no-no if you're writing multithreaded code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C99's `snprintf` prints to a string and guarantees not to overflow the buffer:

```
char msg[48];

snprintf(msg, sizeof(msg),
    "Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

`snprintf` returns the number of characters that would have been written had the string been large enough. So if the returned values is equal to or larger than the buffer size, the string was truncated.

It is legal to pass a buffer size of zero and a null pointer, so that you can do your own allocation by making a probing call first:

```
char *msg;
int n;

n = snprintf(NULL, 0,
    "Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);

msg = malloc(n + 1);
n = snprintf(msg, n + 1,
    "Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);

// do stuff with msg

free(msg);
```

On GNU compilers, the non-sandard function `asprintf` will do that for you:

```
char *msg = asprintf("Player %s has lost %d hitpoints",
    victim.name, damage);

// do stuff with msg

free(msg);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sprintf()`. Like this

```
char* myString = malloc(50);

sprintf(myString, "Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

---

As you would have guessed, it stands for *string printf*

---

Do notice that `sprintf()` requires a `char*`, not `uint8_t`.

---

Offcourse you can also use `snprintf()`. The added advantage is that you can give the number of characters to be copied to the string. This can prevent buffer overflows.

```
char* myString = malloc(50);

snprintf(myString, 50, "Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

Comment: Use `snprintf` instead when possible.

Comment: @user694733, thanx.. added.. :)

Comment: @Haris It is worth pointing out that in your example snprintf will only write 49 chars. One is always reserved for the null terminator.

Comment: [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736930/concatenate-a-string-like-in-printf#comment55254464_33737198) also applies here.  Best to check the return value of `snprintf()`

Answer (score 4):

Everyone is suggesting `sprintf`, but in my opinion it is much better to always use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/). The function prototype is as follows:

```
int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );
```

The first argument is your string buffer, the second argument is its maximum capacity, followed by a format specifier string and the arguments. Example usage:

```
char str[STR_LEN];
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

Note that while this will never do anything illegal (using `sprintf` you could produce undefined behavior), if your buffer is not long enough the string will be truncated, which might result in some surprising output. It's best if you check the result of `snprintf` to see how many characters were really written (thanks to chux for pointing this out).

If you're interested in being able to write code like the one in your question, where the string is *returned* to you from a formatting function, you may find Carmack's `va` from his idTech3 engine interesting: https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena/blob/master/code/splines/q_shared.cpp
 (line 700). Note that you should understand how this works and its possible implications for nested calls, no to mention the problems that could arise if you were to use this in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Unless the result of `snprintf()` is checked, the UB of over-flowing a buffer using `sprintf()` now risks code proceeding with a truncated buffer from `snprintf()`.  Else output could be `"Player long_name has lost"`.  Best to check the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
   char str[MAX_LEN];
   sprintf(str,"Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

but I am not sure it is very safe to pass `uint8_t*` to `sprintf` instead of `char *`. (it maybe constraint violation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535814/pass-unsigned-char-pointer-to-atoi-without-cast) for more details about similar situation).

Indeed for more security you can as well use `snprintf`.

Comment: Use `snprintf` instead when possible.

Comment: @user694733 you mean because there you are able to specify max bytes written?

Comment: @Magisch Yes, to prevent overflows.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

If you want to save the result in a string rather then print it, there is another function from the same family available, called `sprintf`. In your case, use it like this:

```
sprintf(myString,"Player %s has lost %d hitpoints", victim.name, damage);
```

[Further info on sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

As user694733 has pointed out, it is usually safer to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`. The difference between the two is that for `snprintf` you get to specify the maximum amount of chars to write into a string (this includes the terminator char `\0`!" in the second argument. [More info on snprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)

Comment: Use `snprintf` instead when possible.

Comment: @user694733 I added a notation discussing this to my answer, with credit.