# Pointer conversion in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following lines:

```
char *name = malloc(strsize + 1);
```

and

```
uint8_t *data;
data = (uint8_t *)name;
```

It is correct? It doesn't exist a chance that the pointer *name will be interpreted bad when that conversion is done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion between uint8 and char in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264923/conversion-between-uint8-and-char-in-c)

Comment: Out of interest, why don't you malloc directly to uint8_t*?

Comment: because i need to find a HUGE exploit in a program which was wrote by someone (he says that there is an exploit) and i need to find it and i was wondering if this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be much of a problem, except that the *signedness* of the memory would be interpreted differently between access along `data` and `name`. In most of the practical platforms, the size of `char` and `uint8_t` in bits is the same.

Comment: and if they are interpreted differently you may access a memory location which you don't want?

Comment: @user6575913 it's the signness of the data interpreted, **not** the signness of the pointer

Comment: @user6575913 Example: `data[0] = 255;` printing `(int)name[0]` will yield -1. This can be confusing, but you're not accessing any "forbidden" memory

Comment: `In most of the practical platforms, sizeof char is "1",` sizeof(char) is 1 on **all** platforms, by definition.

Comment: Any better now?

Answer (score 0):

No, the conversion is legal. However, problems will arise when you try to print `data`, because you no longer have a `char*`. Other than that the casting is fully supported.